# How to insert new column in excel with value in increasing order?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there any way that I can insert value in a column in increasing order just by calculation?

I'm have never worked with excel, to be precise worked with calculation in excel.

I tried searching on how to increment value in a column in excel and such other queries in google but unable to find any solution to it.

[image]

As you can see in the image value is in incremental order..say for first row I started with 1006453 and from there it starts incrementing by 1 for each row.

Also, excel value is prefilled and I want to add data column with value and increasing till the the end of excel.

Please let me know if anyone needs any further details.

Comment: If the first value is in `A2`, in `A3` you can use `=A$2+ROW()-2` and copy down; if the first value is in `A3`, in `A4`  you can use `=A$3+Row()-3` and copy down;... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can drag down youe data column, and it will automatically increase the values by 1.

The reason is, excel is clever enough to understand the pattern in the data:
[image]

Or, you can create a formula that refers to previous row and previous column, and drag it down:
[image]

You only need to type the formula in B3, and drag it down.